# NodeJS require several scripts to execute in sync

Tags: node.js

I am a NodeJS and Stack Overflow newbie so I hope you won't find this question insulting :)
I have created several scripts that help me automate my daily work (integrate prices and stocks from different suppliers).
Now I need to execute my code in order so that scripts(independent .js files) execute 1 after another when I launch my main "app.js" file. I have tried to "nest" all the functions but that doesn't work.
I was looking for solution for 2 days and can't run in a loop anymore so I hope that someone with more experience can help me.

```
var myConfig1 = require('./first.js');
var myConfig2 = require('./second.js');
var myConfig3 = require('./third.js');
myConfig1.one();
myConfig2.two();
myConfig3.three();
```

So when I run this second script runs first then first one... I do know it's due to async nature of nodeJS but I can't make it work properly.

Code from first.js

```
exports.one = function(){
let mysql = require('mysql');
var fs = require('fs');
let connection = mysql.createConnection({
    host: '///',
    user: '///',
    password: '///',
    database: '///'
});
connection.connect(function(err) {
    if (err) throw err;

    connection.query("SELECT * FROM `2UyqqIA_postmeta` WHERE `meta_key` LIKE '_sku'", function (err, results) {
        if (err) throw err;           

      fs.writeFile('sku.json', JSON.stringify(results), function (err) {
          if (err) throw err;
          console.log('SKU Saved!');
        });
    });
    connection.query("SELECT * FROM `2UyqqIA_postmeta` WHERE `meta_key` LIKE '_stock'", function (err, results) {
      if (err) throw err;           

    fs.writeFile('stock.json', JSON.stringify(results), function (err) {
        if (err) throw err;
        console.log('Stock Saved!');
      });
    });
connection.query("SELECT * FROM `2UyqqIA_postmeta` WHERE `meta_key` LIKE '_price'", function (err, results) {
    if (err) throw err;           

  fs.writeFile('price.json', JSON.stringify(results), function (err) {
      if (err) throw err;
      console.log('Price Saved!');
    });
  connection.end(function(err) {
      // The connection is terminated now
    });

});
});
}
```

second.js

```
exports.two = function(){
const mongodb = require('mongodb')
var MongoClient = mongodb.MongoClient
const url = 'mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017'
const databaseName = 'products'
var fs = require('fs')


fs.readFile('./sku.json', 'utf8', function (err, data) {
    if (err) throw err;   
    var json = JSON.parse(data);
    console.log(json.length)
    MongoClient.connect(url, function(err, db) {
    if (err) throw err;
    var dbo = db.db("mydb");
    for(var k = 0; k < json.length; k++){
    var myquery = { post_id: json[k].post_id };    
    var newvalues = { $set: {_id: json[k].post_id, sku: String(json[k].meta_value) } };
    dbo.collection("products").updateOne(myquery, newvalues, { upsert:true }, function(err, res) {
      if (err) throw err;

      db.close();
    });
    }
    console.log("SKU updated");
  });
})
fs.readFile('./price.json', 'utf8', function (err, data) {
    if (err) throw err;   
    var json = JSON.parse(data);
    console.log(json.length)
    MongoClient.connect(url, function(err, db) {
    if (err) throw err;
    var dbo = db.db("mydb");
    for(var k = 0; k < json.length; k++){
    var myquery = { post_id: json[k].post_id };
    var newvalues = { $set: {_id: json[k].post_id, price: Number(json[k].meta_value) } };
    dbo.collection("products").updateOne(myquery, newvalues, { upsert:true }, function(err, res) {
      if (err) throw err;

      db.close();
    });
    }
    console.log("Price updated");
  });
})
fs.readFile('./stock.json', 'utf8', function (err, data) {
    if (err) throw err;   
    var json = JSON.parse(data);
    console.log(json.length)
    MongoClient.connect(url, function(err, db) {
    if (err) throw err;
    var dbo = db.db("mydb");
    for(var k = 0; k < json.length; k++){
    var myquery = { post_id: json[k].post_id };
    var newvalues = { $set: {_id: json[k].post_id, quantity: Number(json[k].meta_value) } };
    dbo.collection("products").updateOne(myquery, newvalues, { upsert:true }, function(err, res) {
      if (err) throw err;

      db.close();
    });
    }
    console.log("Qty updated");
  });
})
}
```

Comment: Can you show a bit of the code that you have in the required files?

Comment: This will depend on what's inside of `first.js`, `second.js`, and `third.js` - we will have to see more code to help.

Comment: Sure, I have added first 2 .js files. There are 10 in total, but I thought that with an example of 3 I can find a workable solution.

Comment: I think you should return promises where you use `fs` and then `await` them to be resolved.

Comment: Thanks! I will play-around with Ashish Modi example and when/if I make it work will elaborate further here.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming these three functions are asynchronous functions. You have two choices here

use `async/await`

```
(async() => {
  await myConfig1.one();
  await myConfig2.two();
  await myConfig3.three();

})();
```

Use `.then` for promises

```
myConfig1.one()
 .then(() => myConfig2.two())
 .then(() => myConfig3.three());
```

This means thay you are waiting for your first function to complete and then move to next one. Hope this helps

Comment: Unfortunately it doesn't work. So what happens, in async/await version it starts second function before the first one generated required .json files so it fails. In .then version - Cannot read property 'then' of undefined.

Comment: @princessMoo this is the way to go - but you need to return a promise in those functions - so wrap those callbacks into promises or check docks for a promise based approach

Comment: @Estradiaz So you think that I should research variant number 2? (with .then)

Comment: @princessMoo what i mean is you need to `exports.one = function(){ return /*a promsie*/ ... }`

Comment: Even with this it doesn't work. It throws an "Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open './sku.json'" because second script starts running before the first one finishes and generates those files. It will take a while to figure it out. Having C and Python background this looks like SciFi to me :)